# Getting duplicate values from table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, datatable

I am using VS10 & MSSQL2008. I have two table.

[image: Gesellschaft_Sparte_temp]

***Gesellschaft_Sparte_temp***

[image: fr_vertrag]

***fr_vertrag***

```
string conS = "Data Source=RIYAD-PC;Initial Catalog=TestDB;Integrated Security=True";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conS);

        string qs1 = "Select Distinct Gesellschaft_ID from Gesellschaft_Sparte_temp" ;
        string qs2 = "select distinct gesellschaft_id,gesellschaft from fr_vertrag";
        con.Open();

        DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
        DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();

        SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter(qs1, conS);
        SqlDataAdapter da2 = new SqlDataAdapter(qs2, conS);

        da1.Fill(dt1);
        da2.Fill(dt2);
```

Now i have two datatable. I want to update **Gesellscaft_Name** = **fr_vertrag**. **gesellscaft_name**  in **Gesellschaft_Sparte_temp** table where **Gesellschaft_ID** = **fr_vertrag**. **gesellschaft_id**.

But if in **fr_vertrag** table, any of the distinct **gesellschaft_id** have duplicates with different **gesellschaft** value, then those data(**gesellschaft_id** , **gesellschaft**) will be put in a datatable with similar column name.

Here i have few duplicates. A picture For you of a query result in **fr_vertrag**:

```
select distinct gesellschaft_id,gesellschaft from fr_vertrag
```

[image]

How could I get these duplicate values?

Comment: I'm confused as to what you are trying to accomplish. It seems that a having clause would show all of the duplicates.

Comment: Also, there is no need to create multiple data tables.

Comment: I'm confused too. I agree with jfin3204. I advise you to correct your tables' structure rather than trying to remove duplicates

Answer (score 1):

I believe you would want:

```
select distinct gesellschaft_id,gesellschaft from fr_vertrag
GROUP BY gesellschaft_id
HAVING COUNT(*)>1
```

Comment: Based on their question you are correct this is the answer, but they are not asking the correct question.